# Udevadm settle not working

Tags: 18.04, mount, encryption, lvm

I just upgraded to 18.04 on my NAS.  I have a script that prompts my user for a luks password and then mounts the drive after it's decrypted. This used to work:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md0 md0_crypt
udevadm settle --exit-if-exists=/dev/mapper/files--vg-main
mount /dev/mapper/files--vg-main /main
```

However after updating to 18.04 this stopped working and I get: `mount: /main: special device /dev/mapper/files--vg-main does not exist.`

I have not found a solution just googling.  My LUKS container is my pv.  I have it in a Vol group called files-vg.  I then have one logical volume with a path `/dev/files-vg/main`. Hence why I'm looking for `/dev/mapper/files--vg-main`

Edit: To clarify, the `udevadm settle` line does not wait long enough for the LV to become available so the mount fails.  I can manually call `mount` and it will work afterward.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `sleep 3` between line 1 and 2?  If that's too much time, try `2`, if too little, try `4`.  Please ping me @Fabby with the results.

Comment: I think that would work but it's inelegant. I'm looking for something to mount the drive as soon as it's available

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly workaround that I don't have a LUKS container to test on:

`udevadm info /dev/mapper/files--vg-main`

Where `/dev/mapper/files--vg-main` is the device you are checking for.
if [ $? -eq 0 ] then the command was successful meaning the device exists and you can mount it.

else you'd have to loop and check again.

As a side note you can find some useful udev debugging ideas on [this page.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUdev)